# Email not working magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, centos, cpanel

I seem to have set up everything correct in magento admin but emails for orders or confirmation or newsletter subscription do not seem to work, they seem to succeed,
But I do not receive any emails

Any one can please help me after trying all?

I use cpanel with whm, centos 7

Do I have to set up special email settings, something I see over my head?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Is it a case that they're not being recieved rather than not being sent https://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: If I place an order or newsletter confirmation, I receive no confirmations and they also got not send. 

What I see over my head?
Thanks Alain

Comment: @AlainStout, configure SMTP..

Comment: I have done that too @jafarpinjar